# Mysql select case as WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

Can't we do this ??

```
SELECT tbl_ads.*, CASE tbl_ads.type
  WHEN 'private'
       THEN (select tbl_privatesellers.privateseller_state from tbl_privatesellers where     tbl_privatesellers.privateseller_id = tbl_ads.privateseller_id  )
  WHEN 'dealer'
       THEN (select tbl_dealer.state from tbl_dealer where tbl_dealer.id = tbl_ads.privateseller_id )
END AS state 
FROM tbl_ads WHERE ad_status = 1 AND state = 'ACT'
```

Its giving error as unknown column state

Comment: Obviously you do not have column `state` in the table `tbl_ads`.

Comment: yes i havent but state is being created by case end as state 
plus its shown in mysql results as appeared in phpmyadmin 

How can i used that state in where condition??

Comment: Expression aliases should be used in `having` clause, not in `where`.

Comment: Show us the *full* error message. The relevant table schemata would also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions results are not seen in `WHERE` clause because it's conditions are checked first, before calculating expressions for the rows. Place it in `HAVING` clause like that

```
...
HAVING state='ACT'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT is evaluated at the end, before WHERE clause, 
conditions in WHERE clause cannot refer to expressions evaluated in SELECT.
Move (or copy) the condition from SELECT to WHERE.

```
SELECT ..........
FROM tbl_ads 
WHERE ad_status = 1 
  AND  'ACT'  =  
     CASE tbl_ads.type
       WHEN 'private'
       THEN (select tbl_privatesellers.privateseller_state 
             from tbl_privatesellers 
             where     tbl_privatesellers.privateseller_id = tbl_ads.privateseller_id  )
       WHEN 'dealer'
       THEN (select tbl_dealer.state 
             from tbl_dealer 
             where tbl_dealer.id = tbl_ads.privateseller_id )
     END
```